# Getting Stereo Mix to listen to Optical Out

Tags: windows, sound-card

I'm unable to get Stereo Mix to listen to the optical output I've set all my devices to use. It doesn't seem to be responding to any audio, and I can't seem to use it for anything else.

Running Win8.1 with Realtek soundcard on a Gigabyte UD6 motherboard.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stereo mix is implemented by the driver, and I suspect this just might not be possible. A potential alternative is Virtual Audio Cable.

Comment: @Bob I've tried VAC but it doesn't seem to do what I require, which is essentially a clone of my audio output to mix independently with my mic, effectively so I could stream what I'm hearing and broadcast it over the mic channels.

Comment: That's exactly what VAC is often used for. VAC installs an audio output device, which you should send your audio output to. It then sends it to the matching input device, which behaves much like stereo mix. You can use the repeater program that comes with VAC to repeat this input stream to your actual physical output device.